# Fog overlay won't loop itself on the x-axis for animation marquee effect

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've tried adapting the code from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arthjRwm5VU) to my own project and I can't figure out why the fog overlay won't repeat itself on the x-axis.
Here's the code, hopefully you guys will be able to help me ^^ I am still a beginner in the coding world.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.fog {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.absolute-bg {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fog-container {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fog-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fog-img-first {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background: url(fog-1.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  animation: marquee 60s linear infinite;
}

.fog-img-second {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background: url(fog-2.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  animation: marquee 60s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-200vw, 0, 0);
  }
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 98vw;
  height: 98vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#homescreen {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(main-background.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="homescreen">
  <section class="fog">
    <div class="absolute-bg">
      <div class="fog-container">
        <div class="fog-img fog-img-first"></div>
        <div class="fog-img fog-img-second"></div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <img src="logo v3.png" class="logo"><br>
      <div id="buttonsDiv">
        <button class="menuButtons" onclick="fadeOut(homeScreen)">PLAY</button>&nbsp
        <button class="menuButtons">SETTINGS</button><br>
        <button class="menuButtons">CREDITS</button><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I've tried using chatGPT but it doesn't seem to be able to help me and all of the discord code support servers I've joined were deserted so I came here. One thing I did in the code which almost fixed my issue is I increased the width in the .fog-img class selector and the fog overlay did repeat itself on the x-axis but not indefinitely, only by the value I put in the .fog-img which is not what I want. No errors in the dev tools tho!

Answer (score 0):

Easy just remove the `background-size: contain;`. That's what's causing your issue. It prevents the repeat from doing its job